# Проблема при запуске кода на С++ в Qt на линуксе

Tags: qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12/bits/os_defines.h:39: ошибка: features.h: No such file or directory In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12/bits/c++config.h:655, from /usr/include/c++/12/iostream:38, from /home/user/MyCode/FirstApp/main.cpp:1: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/12/bits/os_defines.h:39:10: fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory 39 | #include <features.h> | ^~~~~~~~~~~~ :-1:

ошибка: [CMakeFiles/FirstApp.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/FirstApp.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1

Компилятор clang не установлен, но установлен g++

Comment: в чем вопрос? в ошибке ясно написано, что не существует указанного файла

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39157579/4711135

Comment: Невозможно найти пакет system.devel
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «system.devel»